# How to run a second command in same screen session

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I'm starting the first command in screen like this:

```
screen -d -m -S testen -t lalala watch df -h
```

which gives me a screen session running in the background and I can reconnect at a later time.

How can I run a second command in a new window in the same screen session?

Answer (score 13):

Start a named screen session (`-S`) with a named window (`-t`) adapting to the terminal size (`-A`) in detached mode (`-d -m`):

```
screen -S mySessionName -t myWinName0 -A -d -m
```

Start another named window (`-t`) in the same screen session (`-S`):

```
screen -S mySessionName -X screen -t myWinName2
```

Stuff a few commands (`-X stuff $'cmds'`) into the first named window (`-p`) in the session (`-S`):

```
screen -S mySessionName -p myWinName0 -X stuff $'echo myWinName0\necho cmd1\necho cmd2\n'
```

Stuff a few commands (`-X stuff $'cmds'`) into the second named window (`-p`) in the session (`-S`):

```
screen -S mySessionName -p myWinName1 -X stuff $'echo myWinName1\necho cmd1\necho cmd2\n'
```

List the screen sessions and reattach to see what happened:

```
screen -ls
screen -r mySessionName
```

Note: The linefeed (`\n`) simulates pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  You could use semicolons to separate commands as well.

Comment: You don't have to do the "stuff" bits.

`screen -S sessionName -t windowName1 -Adm <command> && screen -S sessionName -X screen -t windowName2 -Adm <command2>`

Answer (score 6):

Tried above approach, but the second command didn't execute on the second window. I slightly adjusted the example by using the window number, instead of the window name:

1. create session

   ```
   screen -S mySessionName -t 0 -A -d -m
   ```
2. create second window

   ```
   screen -S mySessionName -X screen -t 1
   ```
3. send command to first window

   ```
   screen -S mySessionName -p 0 -X stuff $'echo myWinName0\necho cmd1\necho cmd2\n'
   ```
4. send command to second window

   ```
   screen -S mySessionName -p 1 -X stuff $'echo myWinName0\necho cmd1\necho cmd2\n'
   ```
5. now check if the command has been runned on the first window

   ```
   screen -R mySessionName -p 0
   ```
6. now check if the command has been runned on the second window

   ```
   screen -R mySessionName -p 1
   ```

Tested with Screen 4.00.03 (CENTOS 6.3 x64).

Answer (score 4):

Inside screen:

- <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd> to open a new shell window
- <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd>, `:screen newcmd` to run `newcmd`

Outside:

```
screen -X testen "screen newcmd"
```

Comment: hi **grawity**, i know this, but i would like to do it from an init script. basically i want to start 2 commands in seperate windows in the same screen session. see you

Comment: @bob: See example #3, "Outside screen", in this answer.

Comment: hi grawity, `screen -S testen -X 'screen echo "hi"'` doesn't work.

Comment: I was also unable to get the -X method to work. Fwiw, my screen -v says "Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06"

Answer (score 2):

You can setup an alternate .screenrc via the `-c` argument.  In this new screenrc you can setup multiple commands to start when the screen session is initialized.

At the end of this alternate .screenrc put the following commands:

```
screen 1 cmd1 args
screen 2 cmd2 args
```

You don't need to setup an alternate configuration file if you only plan to run one type of screen session and the default commands run are always fine.